# Error sending a email to a Gmail account with SMTP

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, gmail

I am using a smtp service for send some emails with a pdf attachment, when I send the email to a Outlook account works well but with some accounts of Gmail fails.

This is the email that I receive

[image: the email]

this email contains a txt file with the next information:

> Reporting-MTA: dns; googlemail.com Received-From-MTA: dns;
>   emailExample@domainexample.com Arrival-Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 06:57:25
>   -0700 (PDT) X-Original-Message-ID: <5d77abc5.1c69fb81.74950.6a27SMTPIN_ADDED_MISSING@mx.google.com>
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; otheremailexample@otherdomainexample.es
>   Action: failed Status: 5.0.0 Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019
>   06:57:26 -0700 (PDT)

Anyone knows what is happening and what's the solution?

Pd: This is the code that I use:

```
Dim contentType As New System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf)
    Dim att As Net.Mail.Attachment = New Net.Mail.Attachment("pathOfPdf.pdf", contentType)
    att.ContentDisposition.FileName = "nameAttachent"
    Using MM As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()

        MM.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress("myMail.smpt.com")

        Dim cultureOld As CultureInfo = My.Resources.MsjForm.Culture
        My.Resources.MsjForm.Culture = New CultureInfo("LanguageOfTheReceptor")
        MM.Subject = "Subject"  
        My.Resources.MsjForm.Culture = cultureOld
        MM.To.Add("ToEmail@gmail.com")
        MM.Attachments.Add(att)
        Dim SMTP As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient() With {.Host = "hostSMTP", .Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("AccountSMTP", "PassSMTP")}
        SMTP.Send(MM)
    End Using
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Have you seen [SMTP mails being rejected by receiver](https://serverfault.com/questions/283666/smtp-mails-being-rejected-by-receiver)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton the message that this user receives is different to the message that I reveive.

Comment: @Krever 1) We had no way of knowing that. 2) Check "hostSMTP" with some email server checking service such as [MXToolBox](https://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx) - it might reveal some things to change to make it more likely that the email will get through.